# footer animation with button

Tags: javascript, html, css, footer

The issue I have having is a need to build a footer that only appear when you have scrolled to the bottom of the page. then once at the bottom the footer animates up. It is no problem if it over laps what is on the bottom. I also need a button in the top right corner so that the footer goes back down and disappears. My client wants what https://yorkcapital.com/ has... you sometimes have to scroll down and force it to comes up by trying to scroll down more. Ive never created a footer like this... Please help. I just never thought about using a footer this way. please please help. thanks everyone!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how to ask good questions that are on-topic for this forum. Then write some code to attempt to solve your problem yourself, and if you get stuck, post a question with a [mcve] showing what you've tried and what isn't working.

Comment: That footer on York Capital looks like a bit of a UI nightmare to me at least on a touch device. I’ve just tried it on an iPad and I got the footer to show, but only for as long as I had my finger on the screen. Is that what is required?